# What's the difference between CFRelease and CFSafeRelease?

Tags: xcode, macos

What's the difference between CFRelease and CFSafeRelease?
Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the provided documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: What _is_ CFSafeRelease? It isn't an Apple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard thing called `CFSafeRelease`. You probably have a macro or function in your local code that defines something like:

```
#define CFSafeRelease(x) if (x) { CFRelease(x); x = NULL; }
```

Or something like that. This is a pretty common macro (though it's usually given a name like `MYSafeRelease` or something else to keep it from looking like it's builtin).

Of course, occasionally you'll find it defined [this way](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ChatServer/ChatServer-373/jabber_od_auth/jabber_od_auth_test/jabber_od_auth_digest_md5_test.m):

```
#define CFSafeRelease( cfobj ) if ( cfobj != NULL ) CFRelease( cfobj );
```

Which certainly is *not* a "safe release" since it leaves a dangling pointer....